# ajax data not loading

Tags: ajax, json, asynchronous

I am trying to code a simple customer mobile page.
On the first page, i have names of each customer. `onclick` of one of them, it's open this file contain code below, however no data is loading. But if I try the refresh page, it works!

---

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
window.onload=function()
{

   url = 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
   encodeURIComponent('http://www.mydomain.com/myphpfile.php') + '&callback=?';
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 4000,
      success: function(reponse){
      a=reponse.contents.split(';'); 
      document.getElementById("client").innerHTML = a[0] ;
      document.getElementById("adresse1").innerHTML = a[1] ;
},

});

}

</script>
```

Comment: where is the type ? type='get' or type='post'  ?

Comment: @samitha jquery defaults to `GET` which I assume he wants, based off the way he is working with the response data.

Comment: It is because you have written the ajax call in the window.onload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you dont need to include the `'&callback=?';` param as jQuery will handle that automatically as long as you have `dataType: 'JSONP'`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent('http://www.mydomain.com/myphpfile.php');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url='+encoded,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      timeout: 4000
    }).done(function(reponse){
        //do your work 
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank's it's work !

Another problem in same subjet:

Ajax doesn't send data parameters to php file 
-> data: {'numcli': id},
in my php file : nothing is read:

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url='+encoded,
  type:'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {'numcli': id},
//

***php file

<?php
//code
$id = $_GET['numcli'];
//$id seems empty
?>

Comment: thanks profuse for your answer it solved my problem, I have one problem. non english characters are strange (square) when it retreives the html. I have checked it with fiddler it seems that whateverorigin sends strange characters. I have sent charset, contentTYpe and scriptCharset (Utf-8) with the request.